Spring Boot: NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException with Multiple Interceptors
in an existing Spring Boot application, there is a metric interceptor configured as follows:
@Component("metricsInterceptorInternal")
public class MetricsInterceptorInternal extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    // implementation details
}

The interceptor is configured in WebConfig as follows:
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("metricsInterceptorInternal")
    private HandlerInterceptorAdapter metricsInterceptor;

    // configuration details
}

Additionally, there's a dependency in the pom.xml that also injects a MetricsInterceptor bean without any qualifier:
@Component
public class MetricsInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    // implementation details
}

This dependency has its configuration as well as follows:
@Configuration
public class InterceptorConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private HandlerInterceptorAdapter metricsInterceptor;

    // configuration details
}

Despite using a qualifier, I'm encountering the following error when starting the application:
Error creating bean with name 'interceptorConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setRequestResponseContextInterceptor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: metricsInterceptorInternal,metricsInterceptor
Details:
The root cause of the BeanCreationException is: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: metricsInterceptorInternal,metricsInterceptor

Is there a way to resolve this issue while keeping the dependency in the pom.xml? Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

What is setRequestResponseContextInterceptor?

try changing your InterceptorConfiguration to also use a @Qualifier
@Configuration
public class InterceptorConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("metricsInterceptor") // referencing the default bean id (from class name)
    private HandlerInterceptorAdapter metricsInterceptor;

    // configuration details
}


For you to be able to use one without @Qualifier you would need it to have @Primary over MetricsInterceptor. Since, if I understood correctly, it is in some library you can redefine it in your application in some @Configuration file:
@Configuration
public class SomeConfig {
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public HandlerInterceptorAdapter metricsInterceptor() {
        return new MetricsInterceptor();
    }
}

